# HashBytes() Function T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What's the most efficient way to convert the output of this function from a varbinary() to a a varchar()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binvalue)
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2008 use

```
CONVERT(varchar, @binary, 1)
```

1 - style 0x060D,
2 - 060D

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

CONVERT(varchar, @binary)